# Floating Point with 3 Digits after Point in Android

Tags: android

What to do if I want 3 digits after point in a Floating point number?

If `Float amt=1243343.43214;` Then I want the value of `amt` as `1243343.432`

Comment: Look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Look [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

```
    Float amt = 1243343.43214f;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");

    System.out.println(df.format(amt));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help